# How to check for how long Oracle DBMS_LOCK was acquired (timing)?

Tags: database, oracle

I'm using Oracle DBMS_LOCK in a stored procedure, wanted for how much time was procedure acquired the lock !

Answer (score 1):

You might want to elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, but to answer the question as written, you would need to query V$LOCK.